# Show progress bar when compressing with py7zr

Tags: python, progress-bar, 7zip, py7zr

I'm using [py7zr](https://pypi.org/project/py7zr/) to compress a very large file.

I'm using this syntax from the example:

```
with py7zr.SevenZipFile('target.7z', 'w') as z:
    z.writeall('./base_dir')
```

Being the file very large, I would like to show a progress bar.

Since I know how to show a progress bar, both using tqdm or enlighten, specifically I want to know how to have py7zr doing the compression a bit at a time, and retrieve the status of the compression periodically from py7zr.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to know how to show a progress bar on the screen or how to get progress information from the in-progress compression? They are two quite different questions and there's not a lot of detail in your question.

Comment: In loop use write instead of writeall, calculate sizeof(files_compressed)/sizeof(total_files_to_be_compressed) * 100. Show progress bar using tqdm.

Comment: @Kemp I want to know how to get progress information from py7zr. I have edited my question. Thanks for pointing out my question was ambiguous.

Comment: How `sizeof(files_compressed)/sizeof(total_files_to_be_compressed) * 100` are supposed to work? By definition of compression, files_compressed < total_files_to_be_compressed, so that calculation would never reach 100%